# I am not getting any results after pressing submit in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I was hoping that when I click on the `submit` of html, my `find_winner()` will run and `result` to be shown on my `{{results}}`.

But when I click on the button, nothing is happening

My html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/">        
        {{ form.submit }} 
     </form>    

<div id=result>
 

<h3>Computer cards: {{computer_deck}} </h3>
  
<h3>Your cards: {{user_deck}}</h3>

<h2>Results: {{result}}</h2>
```

Section of my python and Flask:

```
SEQUENCE = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
            'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
VALUES = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9,
          '10': 10, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, 'K': 13, 'A': 14}
SUITS = ['S', 'H', 'C', 'D']



# The computer gets 5 cards
def make_cards(deck = None):
    result_deck = set()
    while (len(result_deck) < 5):
        card = random.choice(SEQUENCE) + random.choice(SUITS)
        if (deck != None):
            if (card not in deck): 
                result_deck.add(card)
        else:
            result_deck.add(card)
    return list(result_deck)

def poker_hand_ranking(deck):
    hand = deck
    suits = sorted([card[-1] for card in hand])
    faces = sorted([card[:-1] for card in hand])
    if is_royal_flush(hand, suits, faces):
        return 1, "You have a Royal Flush"
    elif is_straight_flush(hand, suits, faces):
        return 2, "You have a Straight Flush"
    elif is_four_of_a_kind(hand, suits, faces):
        return 3, "You have four of a Kind"
    elif is_full_house(hand, suits, faces):
        return 4, "You have a full House"
    elif is_flush(hand, suits, faces):
        return 5, "You have a flush"
    elif is_straight(hand, suits, faces):
        return 6, "You have a straight"
    elif is_three_of_a_kind(hand, suits, faces):
        return 7, "You have a three of a Kind"
    elif is_two_pairs(hand, suits, faces):
        return 8, "You have a two Pair"
    elif is_one_pair(hand, suits, faces):
        return 9, "You have a pair"
    else:
        #if none of these counts:
        return 10, "High Card"


def find_winner(user_deck, computer_deck):
    user_rank = poker_hand_ranking(user_deck)
    computer_rank = poker_hand_ranking(computer_deck)
    if (user_rank[0] < computer_rank[0]):
        print('Winner is user')
    elif (user_rank[0] > computer_rank[0]):
        print('Winner is computer')
    else:
        print('Draw!')
    print('User:', user_deck, user_rank[1])
    print('Computer:', computer_deck, computer_rank[1])

class getresult(FlaskForm): 
    submit = SubmitField('Click to see the winner')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def homepage():
    card_form = getresult()
    if card_form.validate_on_submit():
        user_deck = make_cards()
        computer_deck = make_cards(user_deck)
        result = find_winner(user_deck, computer_deck)
        return render_template('index.html', form=card_form,
                                user_deck=user_deck,
                                computer_deck=computer_deck,
                                result=result)
    return render_template('index.html', form=card_form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # print(poker_hand_ranking(["10H", "JH", "QH", "AH", "KH"]))
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML needed

```
{{ form.csrf_token }}      
{{ form.submit }}
```